# how to reduce the div height

Tags: css, jsp

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">
    <div class="control-group checkForError">
      <label class="control-label" for="Client">Client</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input style="height: 100px" type="text" name="Client" id="Client" readonly="readonly" class="m-wrap span4 clrField" tabindex="1">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" readonly="readonly" class="m-wrap span8 clrField" tabindex="2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to reduce the div height.
I am tried with min-height but its not reduces.
If I increase height it is increasing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use max-height not min-height!

```
div{
max-height: 100px;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use max-height instead. It will work fine. the min- height wont work on div.

Comment: i dint copied the answer sir that was the first thought that came into my mind see the time differnce is just few seconds in our answers

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="height:100px">
..............
..........
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A div's height depends on its inner elements, in your example, the first input is having a height of 100px, so the div will have at least 100px height, ignoring spacing, boarder, padding.
Setting max-height on the div will hint the rendering engine to limit the height, but doesn't necessarily work all the time.

I'd suggest you changing the input's height first:

```
<input style="max-height: 100px" type="text" name="Client" id="Client" readonly="readonly" class="m-wrap span4 clrField" tabindex="1" />
```