# How to make a div to grow height with contents but up to a certain height using css

Tags: css

Is there a way using css to make a `div` to grow height as its contents grows but up to a certain height size and from there to show a vertical scrollbar?

Comment: Yes there is. `max-height: 100px`

Comment: @MarkBaijens, thank you... post as an aswer in order to upvote you!

Comment: just don't forget to add the `overflow-y: auto`

Comment: I can't believe. This is a really great question!

Comment: Duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/14732448/2869093 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/22498843/2869093

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is. `max-height: 100px` in combination with `overflow: auto`

```css
.max_height {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="max_height">
  <h2>Small div</h2>
</div>
<div class="max_height">
  <h2>Big div</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut in porta tortor, vel varius mi. Nullam volutpat, dolor nec auctor scelerisque, augue mi dapibus nunc, ut vulputate velit leo dapibus diam. Proin maximus aliquet libero, gravida tempor nisl
    fringilla nec. Curabitur at sem finibus, laoreet neque sed, maximus arcu. Phasellus porta consectetur quam at egestas. Nunc ultrices, tellus ac rutrum aliquam, arcu quam pellentesque augue, non varius justo turpis et nisl. Proin gravida, purus at
    porta dictum, arcu lacus vestibulum nisl, nec tincidunt nisl quam facilisis odio. Vestibulum vel pharetra mauris. Ut non ullamcorper lorem. Nullam a purus in tellus dictum semper vel vel tortor.</p>

  <p>Vestibulum laoreet nisl ut nisl consequat, eget dapibus dui pellentesque. Cras sed urna non diam efficitur auctor sed dapibus purus. Nam sagittis velit nisl, vestibulum pulvinar odio sollicitudin in. Sed varius, sem luctus sagittis dignissim, nunc arcu
    dignissim elit, vitae commodo leo ligula a quam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum fermentum enim nunc, venenatis pellentesque dolor malesuada non. Aenean at hendrerit massa, in porta
    nisl.</p>

  <p>Nulla tincidunt nunc quis molestie ullamcorper. Proin suscipit eleifend metus in sodales. Proin eu lectus condimentum, egestas velit eu, dictum sem. Curabitur varius mollis hendrerit. Integer eleifend bibendum ante eget egestas. Orci varius natoque
    penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi iaculis cursus orci, a eleifend sapien tempor sed. Pellentesque vulputate ullamcorper arcu vel auctor. Nunc gravida, ligula et pellentesque eleifend, purus dui cursus velit,
    ut elementum magna felis in neque. Nulla nec consectetur augue.</p>

  <p>Nam est nisi, gravida a fermentum eu, consectetur sit amet magna. Aenean sed arcu purus. Nam mauris neque, tempus id massa vel, rhoncus mattis tellus. Nulla viverra sapien ante, ut congue neque ullamcorper nec. Maecenas pharetra ipsum ac ex laoreet,
    ac suscipit quam varius. Nunc semper, libero at aliquam ultrices, nunc dolor maximus eros, a blandit est dolor non neque. Nulla non posuere tellus. Nulla aliquet mi ac urna mollis vulputate.</p>

  <p>Sed eu lorem enim. Donec ante mi, egestas quis ultrices ut, commodo nec massa. Mauris maximus vitae lectus eget dapibus. Integer ligula tortor, sollicitudin et mattis sed, faucibus eu tortor. Vestibulum porttitor ante a sem semper, eu convallis orci
    vulputate. Suspendisse aliquam vestibulum lorem, vitae tincidunt purus varius a. Morbi arcu eros, vehicula eget tristique eu, porta ut arcu. Nam aliquam enim sit amet justo blandit, vitae finibus metus vehicula. Integer interdum lacus metus, vel molestie
    eros blandit sed. Donec eu facilisis velit. Nulla nec odio et lectus tempor rutrum. Nunc faucibus diam ut arcu cursus ornare. Nam vel ornare metus.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
div {
    max-height: 100px; /* limit height here */
    overflow-y: auto; /* add this to add scrollbars when needed */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the overflow tip! +1

Answer (score 2):

Use the `max-height` and `overflow` properties:

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: don't forget to add `overflow-y: auto` or just `overflow: auto`, otherwise this won't work as desired

Comment: @Patrick Manser, thanks, you're right!

Answer (score 2):

You set the `max-height` property to the value you want and then `overflow-y: auto` so that the div has a scrollbar once the content exceeds the `max-height`

```
div {
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[Example](https://jsbin.com/zopuhotuju/edit?html,css,output)